# What does "catch up to" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/catch+up

"The debt problem may be **catching up to** consumers, with recent falling property prices a bad signal for retail sales, according to Cousins. House prices in England and Wales slipped last month, in the most lackluster July in five years, according to Acadata and LSL Property Services Plc. House prices had held up partly due to a government program that encouraged first-time buyers to enter the market, according to Cousins."

Source:https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-08-18/pyrford-says-brexit-is-sideshow-consumer-debt-bigger-challenge

Comment: I think it is No2 in this link: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch%20up%20with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the problem may be *getting closer* or *reaching out to* or *starting to influence* the consumers.

Catch up is a phrasal verb that usually means that the subject is reaching the level as some objective

Comment: That's what's in No2 of the link: merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch%20up%20with

Comment: "begin to affect"

Answer (score 2):

I like @Coreplo's "starting to influence".

When an older person feels pain in their knees as they climb the stairs, we might hear them say "My age is **catching up** with me", that is, "I am beginning to feel the effects of getting older".

Applying that to the original quote: consumers are *beginning to experience* the effects of the debt problem.